# My power query isn't deleting uneeded columns

Tags: excel, powerbi

I've got a power query that returns a dynamic number of columns.

If I step through the following steps.

1. Refresh the query which generates a table with 13 columns
2. Refresh the query which generates a table with 8 columns

I find that the table generated in Excel has the 8 columns I expect, plus 5 entirely blank columns left over from the first refresh. I have tried a number of steps including changing the connection settings and the table properties. If possible I'd like to avoid VBA.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: This behaviour can be replicated by adding additional columns on any query, I believe, and then pressing refresh. In my scenario they are just leftover from the query previously returning more columns.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the **Power M Code**?

Comment: It's really simple - it's basically just call an SQL data base and pivot one of the columns (which leaves a dynamic number of columns)

Comment: I would like to have a better idea about of what's going on. Can you post a screenshot with an example of your problem?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for clarity now!

Answer (score 0):

Between your step 1 & 2, I would right-click the Query in the Workbook Queries pane and choose **Load To / Only Create Connection**.  That will delete the entire Excel table.

Then right-click the Query again and choose **Load To / Table / Existing worksheet**.

Comment: The issue is that the users who will be consuming these tables will not know  what power query is, nor what it is doing, and I am trying to avoid having to teach them this kind of information...

Comment: What's "power query"? I'm referring to the "Get & Transform" section of the Data ribbon, baked into Excel (2016+). Just kidding, but I would position it that Excel has new features that they need to learn a little about.

Comment: If needs be then I will for people who will complain about it, I'm just a bit surprised that this is the default behaviour!

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way.